# Error from group_by and map2_dfr in R, returning inconsistent vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame called `biny` which is an observation of about 9k rows geocoded values, 18 columns. I'm trying to loop through and find the next nearest value, with the items grouped by Precinct. the problem is that the mapping here seems to be sending the rows and columns to map2_dfr, instead of the respective latitude and longitude.

```
   dplyr::group_by(PRECINCT) %>%
  purrr::map2_dfr(.$long, .$lat,  
                  ~spatialrisk::points_in_circle(, .x, .y, 
                                                 lon = long, 
                                                 radius = 1000)[2,])

Error: Mapped vectors must have consistent lengths:
* `.x` has length 18
* `.y` has length 8409
```

I've tried so far running this as a data table, as a function, and about a dozen ways in between, and can't get this to run on any of them. not married to the group_by, just want to run that points_in_circle for each respective precinct.

Frustrating element, this works just fine:

```
ans1 <- purrr::map2_dfr(bind$long, bind$lat,  
                ~spatialrisk::points_in_circle(bind, .x, .y, 
                                               lon = long, 
                                               radius = 1000)[2,])
```

I was simply trying to run that on each precinct, but it seems to dislike that option.

Comment: I can post a link to the dataset and the original code, but I feel like I've likely simply mapped something wrong here that a wise R user will see quickly

Comment: The issue is that you didn't specify the `~`

Comment: @akrun you're absolutely right, I did miss the ~, fixing still errors out

Comment: Some doubts are that you looping over 'long', 'lat' columns, and then specify the `lon = long` i.e. the entire column?

Comment: In the update, you said this works just fine.. I assume `biind` is your original dataset and `.x` and `.y` comes from the same data?

Comment: sorry, that a was an unclear edit: that segment works, as I haven't split anything. the ```Lon = long``` is because the spatialrisk::points_in_circle requires that Lon element.

Comment: can you please check the solution posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `group_split` to split by 'PRECINCT', loop over the `list` with `map` and then apply the `map2`

```
out <- bind %>%
       group_split(PRECINCT) %>%
       map(~ {
           dat <- .x
            purrr::map2_dfr(dat$long, dat$lat,             
                ~spatialrisk::points_in_circle(dat, .x, .y, 
                                           lon = long, 
                                           radius = 1000)[2,])
         })
```

Comment: this seems to work brilliantly, is there a reason it kicks out a list instead of a data frame?

Comment: @ike You could use `mutate` or `summarise` after `group_by`, but I was not sure about the behavior of output of `spatialrisk::points_in_circle`.  If it is summarise (in the previous versions, it returns a single row/group.  If mutate, it shoudl returrn the same number of rows (but in 1.0.0, it changed, but still can have some buggy issues) whereas the output in `list` is much more predictable. If you get a `data.frame` as outut with points_in_circle.  instead of `map` use `map_dfr`